# PowerApps | Issue in saving Gallery to SharePoint list

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a simple vertical gallery control with five controls. I am trying to use the below piece of code to save all the rows in gallery to a SharePoint list but I am getting null values.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Logistics` is the name of your SharePoint list, you need to use the Patch overload that has 3 arguments to insert items into the list:

```
ForAll(
    addLogistics.AllItems
    Patch(
        Logistics,
        Defaults(Logistics),
        {
            Title: "123",
            Lot_Number: txtLotNumber.Text,
            Nr_Packs: txtPacks.Text,
            Actual_Weight: txtWeight.Text,
            Sealed: ddSealed.Selected
        }
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add < Defaults(Logistics), > as a second argument in your Patch Function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the text box and drop down controls are inside of gallery, repeating for each item in gallery, you should use the data from gallery items instead of referencing values from controls

For example:

```
ForAll(
    addLogistics.AllItems
    Patch(
        Logistics,
        Defaults(Logistics),
        {
            Title: "123",
            Lot_Number: ThisRecord.LotNumber,
            Nr_Packs: ThisRecord.NrPacks,
            Actual_Weight: ThisRecord.ActualWeight,
            Sealed: ThisRecord.Sealed.Value
        }
    )
);
```

**Note**: Use actual column names at the right hand side instead of `LotNumber`, `NrPacks`, `ActualWeight`, etc.